# tab bar and side menu in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-navigation, native-base

I have used NativeBase tabs for navigation in my application. I have side menu also. items in side menu and tabs are same . my tabs navigation working correctly . I want to navigate through side menu also . how can i do this . here is screen shot. [image: mian screen]

here is menu screen
[image: meun screen]

how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured the navigation through side menu also buy creating ref and passing to props